# IsDate allows "6:00 AM" to validate as a date?

Tags: vb.net

I have a legacy VB.Net app where the user enters a start and an end date. For some reason, the IsDate function in the code below allows "6:00 AM" to pass as a valid date?

How do I fix this?

```
If IsDate(evdetail.ToDate) Then
      .DateTimeEnded = evdetail.ToDate
Else
      .DateTimeEnded = "12/31/2099 6:00:00 AM"
End If
```

Comment: `evdetail.ToDate` is converting it to date

Comment: @Plutonix - ToDate is the field value in the code. There are two boxes, FromDate and ToDate. IsDate checks for a valid date and should not allow 6:00 AM?

Comment: what exactly is `evdetail`?

Comment: How does IsDate(evdetail.ToString) evaluate?

Comment: Function that builds the record to go into the sql database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isdate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the time only string "6:00 AM" is considered valid by `IsDate`.

From the article:

```
Dim firstDate, secondDate As Date
Dim timeOnly, dateAndTime, noDate As String
Dim dateCheck As Boolean
firstDate = CDate("February 12, 1969")
secondDate = #2/12/1969#
timeOnly = "3:45 PM"
dateAndTime = "March 15, 1981 10:22 AM"
noDate = "Hello"
dateCheck = IsDate(firstDate)
dateCheck = IsDate(secondDate)
dateCheck = IsDate(timeOnly) ' <-------
dateCheck = IsDate(dateAndTime)
dateCheck = IsDate(noDate)
```

*In the preceding example, IsDate returns True for the first four calls and False for the last call.*

If you want it to fail as per your comment then look at using [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Something along these lines will do what you want, however I am making the assumption that `evdetail.ToDate` and `.DateTimeEnded` are string types and that the desired locale is en-US.

```
Dim dt As DateTime
Dim ci As New CultureInfo("en-US")
If DateTime.TryParseExact(evdetail.ToDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", ci, DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
    .DateTimeEnded = evdetail.ToDate
Else
    .DateTimeEnded = "12/31/2099 6:00:00 AM"
End If
```

Comment: I read that, what I am not sure about is how to make it fail unless it is a full date, mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt?

Comment: yet another reason to avoid those legacy VB functions

Comment: `DateTime` parse functions might also fail depending on what `.ToDate` is doing.  Whatever `evdetail` is, it might well be just a time, but `.ToDate` implies a transform happening.

Comment: @Plutonix: I initially thought the same as you, then I realised `.ToDate` isn't a member of string. Of course, I'm making the assumption that '.ToDate' is a string member of a struct or class ...

Comment: But it could be a method on a class or structure (something  coded in VB).  There is also a `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices` thing by that name, though I doubt it is involved.

Comment: @Plutonix: This is true, we may never find out ;) He did comment that _ToDate is the field value in the code_, hence my assumption - I've been wrong before though!